# Put one SubView more than once on a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, uiview, uiscrollview

I have an UIScrollView with UIViews being added by lazy-loading algorithm. The UIViews contain previews of previous and next image, so at some point the actual views have to be used more than once (e.g. preview of the 2nd picture is NEXT now, but after 2 page scrolls it is PREVIOUS).

All the UIViews are stored in NSMutableArray and are added dynamically. I have the code, which checks, whether particular UIView is already added to the UIScrollView. If not, the code checks, is there needed UIView in NSMutableArray and if not, creates a new one...

The problem occurs when I try to get an UIView from NSMutableArray, change it's position on the screen and add to UIScrollView again. It just changes it's position and I see white squares where some UIViews have to be.

Is it possible to have 2 UIViews with pointer referred to one memory location or UIImage but with only one different parameter (position)? Is it good idea to copy already created UIView to NSMutable array twice to use with different position? (Win: creation process takes place only once, loss: amount of memory required is doubled).

Comment: Why not use a table view or collection view for this?

Comment: No, you can't. You need to have 2 separate UIViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, I havent fount the good solution, but this worked for me - I just implemented `copy` method in UIView subclass, something like this:

```
- (ExhibitPreview *)copy {
    ExhibitPreview *exhibitPreview =[[ExhibitPreview alloc] initWithImage:self.image];

    exhibitPreview.number.text = self.number.text;
    exhibitPreview.author.text = self.author.text;
    exhibitPreview.title.text = self.title.text;


    exhibitPreview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    exhibitPreview.clipsToBounds = YES;

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth/2, PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
    exhibitPreview.frame = frame;

    return exhibitPreview;
}
```

The first view is view itself and the second I create is a copy.